# React Native, application not running on iphone

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, react-native-ios

the expo server is showing that my mobile application is running on Iphone.

However, on my iphone it is not showing the mobile application.
It is stuck on the page showing " Downloadings Javascript bundle 100.00%.
I don't see any older errors on my CLI either.

Anybody has any idea why?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried restarting the bundler?

Comment: stop the bundler and restart it but this time clear the cache run `npm start -c`